# How to measure performance when different servers are involved to get response?

Tags: performance, testing, view, point

How a request goes from one server to another before sending response back to web browser?

When tried online, I got web browser to web server, but what about other servers like app server and Db server etc.?

Comment: You make a call to your web server. The code on the web server calls the app server if it needs to, which calls the database server if it needs to, etc. You write the code that responds to being called and that calls other functionality that it needs, so you as the developer controls what is called and in what layer -- web server -> app server -> db server, etc.

Comment: I edited your question to make it easier to read, but found: it is almost impossible to do so. Therefore: please improve your question. Make it really clear what your objective is, what you are doing, and where you are stuck. Otherwise people can only guess what you are asking for.